# Codeigniter - Hooks per one controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am using hooks in my CI application "pre_controller hook specifically".
But the problem is Hooks are activated each time a request is issued to any other controller even controllers that i don't want the hook to be activated in.
Can hooks be enabled for only one controller? just like the @Before annotations in playframework.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you put that logic in the Constructor of your controller?

If you have multiple controllers you wish to share this functionality, simply extend the `CI_Controller` with a new class in `application/core/MY_Controller.php` and put the functionality in there, then in the controllers have them extend that class instead of the default CI_Controller (you can add more than one class in `MY_Controller.php`)!

Anything that you put in the override class in `MY_Controller.php` would execute before the code in the rest of the controller, simulating the `pre_controller` hook.

Just remember to call the parent constructor as well:

```
function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
}
```

See the manual for more info about extending the core: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also put your code into a library to use whenever you need it. I ended up using my solution because I could keep my authentication logic separate to my modules. It makes it easier for updating as well.